# How to get elements other than the last element of a two tuple?

Tags: c, tuples

In C, Howcome when I make any n-tuple and try to use it, I can only use the last element of it. Even the type is apparently of the last element of the tuple and not of the tuple itself. How can I get elements other than the last element? I looked quickly through the spec and saw nothing about it.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f() {return 2;}
char* g() {return "dudebro";}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", (f(),g(),3)); /* Should print the address of the tuple (unless it's by-value, in which case it should be a compile error) but prints the last element?*/
    return 0;
}
```

run it:

```
$ gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall -Wextra tt.c -o tt
$ ./tt
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put a bunch of values in commas like this, C will discard all of the values but the rightmost one.  It will evaluate F and G but then ignore them.  I'm not really sure why you think what is supposed to happen should happen.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such thing as a tuple in C.  What you have there is a use of the [*comma operator*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

If you want to collate related data in C, you need to define and use a struct.  And if you want to print out all the data items, you will need an explicit call to `printf` for each one (or use multiple format specifiers).

e.g.

```
typedef struct Foo {
    int a;
    char *b;
};

Foo foo;
foo.a = 5;
foo.b = "hello";

printf("%d %s\n", foo.a, foo.b);
```

Comment: What? why does it let me compile tuple then? how can comma be an operator? does it let you overload the construction of a tuple?

Comment: @megazord: It compiles because it's valid code, it just doesn't do what you anticipated.

Comment: @megazord: You could read the Wikipedia article I linked to; it has several examples.